# HTACCESS Rewrite, remove .php and redirect working for one rule and not the other

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following example urls, there are many possible parameter values

```
http://www.example.com/area-codes.php?code=0000
http://www.example.com/search.php?number=00000000000
```

Which I wish to rewrite to the following, respectively.

```
http://www.example.com/area-codes/0000
http://www.example.com/number/00000000000
```

Currently, the second url is rewriting and redirecting perfectly.
However the top one is causing an Internal server error

Here's my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

#redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php /$1 [R=301,L]    

RewriteRule ^area-codes/([^/]*)$ /area-codes.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^number/([^/]*)$ /search.php?number=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am assuming there's something wrong with my flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented out these two lines and it's worked.

```
#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```